# ManyToMany relation is not saved

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have a user and a movie model. In my app users can save a movie object into the database. I would like to create a relationship between the users and the movies they add.

I get a movie object from my Angular front-end:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Movie createMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie){
    return movieService.createMovie(movie);
}
```

This calls the service and the createMovie function:

```
@Override 
public Movie createMovie(Movie movie) {
    return movieRepository.save(movie);
}
```

The movie object is now added to my movie table in the database, but nothing is added in my `movie_user` table.

In my User.java I have:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
```

And in my Movie.java I have:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.MERGE
})

@JoinTable(name = "movie_user",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
)

private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

In my MySQL workbench I see a `movie_user` table with 2 columns: `movie_id` and `user_id`. When I save a movie nothing happens to the that table.

This is the output from the server:

```
2017-11-07 20:35:04.491  INFO 8140 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] c.m.s.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter       : checking authentication f├╝r user admin
2017-11-07 20:35:04.491  INFO 8140 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_3_, user0_.email as email2_3_, user0_.enabled as enabled3_3_, user0_.firstname as firstnam4_3_, user0_.lastpasswordresetdate as las
tpass5_3_, user0_.lastname as lastname6_3_, user0_.password as password7_3_, user0_.username as username8_3_ from user user0_ where user0_.username=?
Hibernate: select authoritie0_.user_id as user_id1_4_0_, authoritie0_.authority_id as authorit2_4_0_, authority1_.id as id1_0_1_, authority1_.name as name2_0_1_ from
user_authority authoritie0_ inner join authority authority1_ on authoritie0_.authority_id=authority1_.id where authoritie0_.user_id=?
2017-11-07 20:35:04.514  INFO 8140 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] c.m.s.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter       : authenticated user admin, setting security context
Hibernate: select movie0_.id as id1_1_1_, movie0_.name as name2_1_1_, users1_.movie_id as movie_id1_2_3_, user2_.id as user_id2_2_3_, user2_.id as id1_3_0_, user2_.em
ail as email2_3_0_, user2_.enabled as enabled3_3_0_, user2_.firstname as firstnam4_3_0_, user2_.lastpasswordresetdate as lastpass5_3_0_, user2_.lastname as lastname6_
3_0_, user2_.password as password7_3_0_, user2_.username as username8_3_0_ from movie movie0_ left outer join movie_user users1_ on movie0_.id=users1_.movie_id left o
uter join user user2_ on users1_.user_id=user2_.id where movie0_.id=?
Hibernate: select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
Hibernate: insert into movie (name, id) values (?, ?)
```

So it looks like hibernate is doing something with the table but I'm not sure what I should do now. [This is the tutorial that I followed](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Comment: Show, please, how you populate movies and users objects. Maybe you forgrot add movies to users or usert to movie...

Comment: @VladislavKoroteev I'm not sure what you mean. I thought Hibernate/JPA would populate the objects. But I've updated my question with the controller and service.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial says, that

> the add/remove utility methods are mandatory if you use bidirectional
>   associations so that you can make sure that both sides of the
>   association are in sync.

And you need someting like methods `addTag` and `removeTag` from tutorial, because Hibernate doesn't do automatic population. For example

```
class User {

 public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
        movies.add(movie);
        movie.getUsers().add(this);
    }
}
```

So pay little more attention to tutorial and all will works

Comment: Hm I don't seem to understand how this works :/. Sorry. Why should I add a function in my user model to add a movie object? Why can't I just pass the needed values (movie id and user id) to the join table?

Comment: Because of Hibernate's specifics. Framework doesn't know anything about links between entities before you explicitly tell him about them. So we can see in your logs `insert into movie (name, id) values (?, ?)`. Hibernate save only movie, because inside movie there isn't any information about users.

Comment: What should the `getUsers` method do in the movie class? Return a list of users? This isn't explained anywhere.

Comment: Yes, `getUsers` returns list of current users of movie

Comment: So in the user class you have to write a method to add a movie, and in that method you call the getUsers method in the movie class that returns the current user? that makes no sense :/

Comment: Yes, it seems strange, but it's Hibernate :) Movie contains list of users, so for bidirectional mapping you should add movie to user, and user to movies. Read again tutorial, you'll see same thing

Comment: How would I call the addMovie method in the user model from my controller? As you can see in my code I now call the createMovie method in the movieService in the movieController.

Comment: Have you fixed your problem?)